# Inject variables automatically in R function environment

Tags: r

Let's supposed we declare this function:

```
f <- function(x) u + x
```

now if I call `f(10)` R will look for the parent environment for a value of `u` recursively until it reaches the global environment, if a value is found `u + 10` is returned, otherwise we get an error. So far so good.

Now supposed we have a pool from where we would like to pull the unknown values inside the body of `f`, like `pool <- list(u = 10)` or an environment variable with `u` set.

How would you inject the `u` value to a generic function `f`? Can you write a function that injects the variables defined in the `pool` inside `f`? In other words, can we point R in which direction to look for for missing variables instead looking up recursively in the parent environment?

EDIT: I know I can do this `f <- function(x) pool[["u"]] + x` of course, but I'm looking for the behavior described above.

EDIT: The use case is the following: I'm building a library that allow users to configure the function they would like to optimize, and I want them to be allowed to use certain variables already computed when the library is loaded (solutions of certain differential equations) and combine them as they wish. So I'd like to make the process as transparent as possible for them and let them use a variable value `u` instead of `pool$u` in the body of the function if possible.

Comment: You would call upon the object where `u` is stored, no? 

 f <- function(x) pool[["u"]] + x

Comment: Are you asking to scan the entire environment for u or if some object has u within it?

Comment: See updated question

Comment: Add a `...` parameter. Let them specify said list(s) there. Check if they added `...` params, If so, substitute accordingly. This path seems fraught with peril, though. Alternative: have your function be a function generator, Still use `...`, but it'll be a more straightforward implementation, IMO.

Comment: Regarding why `pool <- new.env(); assign("u", 10:15, pool); with(pool. f(1))` does not work in the intended way it is because free variables in a function are looked up in the function's environment, i.e. for function `f` in `environment(f)` -- it has nothing to do with the caller.  Calling the function in a `with` does not change a function's environment hence where it searches for free variables.  `with(pool, f)(1)` would also not change `environment(f)`,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) reset environment** Convert `pool` to an environment and set the environment of `f` to it:

```
# inputs
pool <- list(u = 10)
f <- function(x) u + x

environment(f) <- list2env(pool, parent = environment(f))
f(1)
## [1] 11
```

**2) proto** Another possibility is to use the proto package.  A proto object is an environment with modified methods.  Convert `pool` to a proto object `p` and insert `f` into it.   Inserting `f` into `p` resets its environment to `p` so:

```
library(proto)

p <- as.proto(pool, parent = environment(f))
p$f <- f 
with(p, f(10)) # use the version of f inserted into p
## [1] 11
```

or we could overwrite `f` with the version of `f` in `p`:

```
library(proto)

p <- as.proto(pool, parent = environment(f))
p$f <- f 
f <- with(p, f)
f(1)
## [1] 11
```

**Update:** Have set parent of new environment formed from `pool` to original environment of `f` so that free variables in `f` are first looked up in the environment formed from `pool` and then `f`'s environment in that order rather than the environment derived from `pool` and then the parent frame.

Comment: I like this, it is in the line I was originally thinking